# Can't obtain a closed form expression for an integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to find the result of quite a complicated double integral. While the first part (being a Principal value integral) gave no particular problems, the second one is not providing any closed expression. Here is my code:

```
f[x_]:=(p^2 + k^2 - 2 p k x)/(x - (p^2 + k^2 + 1 - ((p^2 - k^2)^2)/4)/(2 p k))
Integrate[f[x], {x, -1, 1}, PrincipalValue -> True]

ConditionalExpression[1/2 k p (-8 + ((-4 + (k^2 - p^2)^2) ArcCoth[(
 8 k p)/(-4 + k^4 - 4 p^2 + p^4 - 2 k^2 (2 + p^2))])/(k p)), 
k^4 + p^4 < 
  4 + 4 p^2 + 2 k^2 (2 + p^2) && (k - p)^2 (-2 + k + p) (2 + k + p) > 
  4]

g[p_, k_] := 


1/2 k p (-8 + ((-4 + (k^2 - p^2)^2) ArcCoth[(
       8 k p)/(-4 + k^4 - 4 p^2 + p^4 - 2 k^2 (2 + p^2))])/(k p));

nferm[k_]:=1/(Exp[b Sqrt[k^2 + 1]]+1);

Integrate[(k^2 nferm[k])/(2 p k) g[p,k],{k,0,Infinity}]
```

When I tried to run this, 2 or three minutes of waiting and they just threw back the expression without evaluating it. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: There are a lot of integrals that can't be expressed in "closed form" by using OTS functions. Why do you think yours isn't one of them?

Comment: I'm not sure. It's part of a paper that I'm studying for my thesis. They solved it plotted it somehow.

Comment: In order to plot it you just need to solve it numerically. Getting a closed form isn't necessary

Comment: Are k, p, and b all real.  Also, what version of Mathematica are you using?  I obtain a different answer for `Integrate[f[x], {x, -1, 1}, PrincipalValue -> True]` with version 10.1.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I'm using Mathematica 9. It is quite strange because when I ran the Principal Value integral for the first time, I obtained a result in terms of Log. But later, on two or three runs, I got a different answer.

Comment: But, can you tell what result you obtained?

Answer (score 2):

With version 9.0.1,

```
f[x_] := (p^2 + k^2 - 2 p k x)/(x - (p^2 + k^2 + 1 - ((p^2 - k^2)^2)/4)/(2 p k)); 
ans9 = Integrate[f[x], {x, -1, 1}, PrincipalValue -> True]
(* ConditionalExpression[1/2 k p (-8 + ((-4 + (k^2 - p^2)^2) 
   ArcCoth[(8 k p)/(-4 + k^4 - 4 p^2 + p^4 - 2 k^2 (2 + p^2))])/(k p)), 
   k^4 + p^4 < 4 + 4 p^2 + 2 k^2 (2 + p^2) && (k - p)^2 (-2 + k + p) (2 + k + p) > 4] *)
```

Some insight can be gained by plotting the solution ad its region of validity as specified by `ConditionalExpression`,

```
RegionPlot[Evaluate[ans9[[2]]], {k, -5, 5}, {p, -5, 5}, FrameLabel -> {k, p}]
```

[image]

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[ans9[[1]]], {k, -5, 5}, {p, -5, 5}, PlotPoints -> 100,
  PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> None, AxesLabel -> {k, p, z}]
```

[image]

Thus, the solution is real and continuous over a wider range than that given by the `ConditionalExpression`.  Nonetheless, the actual range is bounded by singularities, so it is not surprising that the second `Integrate` in the question does not yield an answer.  Of course, even without the singularities, `Integrate` might fail, if no known symbolic solution exists.

Because, I presume, `k` and `p` are meant to be `Reals`, it is reasonable to inform `Integrate` of this.

```
ans9r = Integrate[f[x], {x, -1, 1}, PrincipalValue -> True, 
  Assumptions -> k ∈ Reals && p ∈ Reals]
(* ConditionalExpression[1/2 k p (-8 + ((-4 + (k^2 - p^2)^2) 
   ArcTanh[(8 k p)/(-4 + k^4 - 4 p^2 + p^4 - 2 k^2 (2 + p^2))])/(k p)),
   (-4 + (k - p)^2) (k + p)^2 <= 4 && (k - p)^2 (-2 + k + p) (2 + k + p) <= 4] *)
```

which produces a different but related solution (perhaps, a different branch).

[image]

[image]

Between them, the two solutions cover all of `p - k` space.  Nonetheless, it is unclear whether patching the two together and then integrating would be successful, due to branchpoints at `z = 1` and `z = -1`, where `z` is the argument of `ArcTanh` or `ArcCoth` in the expressions above.

Answer to question in a comment above: Although version 10.1 produces symbolic solutions that appear different from the version 9.0.1 solutions.

```
(* ConditionalExpression[1/4 (-(-4 + (k^2 - p^2)^2) Log[-k p] + (k^2 - p^2)^2 (Log[k p]
   - Log[4 - (-4 + (k - p)^2) (k + p)^2] + Log[4 - (k - p)^2 (-2 + k + p) (2 + k + p)])
   - 4 (4 k p + Log[k p] - Log[4 - (-4 + (k - p)^2) (k + p)^2] + 
   Log[4 - (k - p)^2 (-2 + k + p) (2 + k + p)])),
   (-4 + k^4 - 4 p^2 + p^4 - 2 k^2 (2 + p^2))/(k p) ∈ Reals] *)
```

and

```
(* ConditionalExpression[1/4 (-16 k p - (-4 + (k^2 - p^2)^2) 
   Log[4 - (-4 + (k - p)^2) (k + p)^2] + (-4 + (k^2 - p^2)^2) 
   Log[4 - (k - p)^2 (-2 + k + p) (2 + k + p)]), 
   k^4 + p^4 <= 4 + 4 p^2 + 2 k^2 (2 + p^2) && (-4 + (k - p)^2) (k + p)^2 <= 4] *)
```

their 3D plots are identical respectively to the fourth and second plots above, although their asserted ranges of validity differ.  Even though a straightforward application of `FullSimplify` does not succeed in showing the respective version 9.0.1 and version 10.1 solutions to be identical, it appears that they are from identities in [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseHyperbolicTangent.html).